# How avoid message about SuperUsers while installing App, Programs in terminal

Tags: command-line

everyone want ask a question how to avoid `[sudo] password for` message by OS while i install Repository on terminal.

sometimes it happen telling if  it's a superusers. it's to Programming, install App by Store Linux it's only for creators or development i think, why it happen ?¿

uploaded image of the terminal. https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYHq1.jpg

[image]

i will uploaded most images while i install new Repository. i want everyone see how Linux think that you are a superuser, without knowledge about it. it's ridiculous

XD?¿ Questions yes, answers No

why? What For?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking, but if you are wanting to remove password requirements for `sudo`; it's been asked before but there are great potential costs to doing it. It means anyone with access to your system can make changes, and take over control of your system and potentially anything you have rights over. The password prompt is there as it protects your systems security.

Comment: hi guiverc thanks you for read it, generally it look like something i wrong while i install App / Programs in the Terminal of Ubuntu 20. LTS i don't why it happen, but i will uploaded most Images when i try again install Programs( Repository, library etc.  i get errors. i don't know how to get access into SuperUsers it's out of my knowledge  computer, i use Windows 7 since 2009 now W10 but i want migrate to Ubuntu.

Comment: Please be specific with details, for example Ubuntu has release that use the *yy* format, eg. Ubuntu Core 20, which is a different product to for example Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 LTS.  Releases that use *yy* format can only use *snaps*, where as *yy.mm* format releases can use *snaps*, *debs* and more being designed for computers, not devices/appliances. All *yy* releases have 10 years of support (longer than *yy.mm*) so LTS isn't mentioned usually. If you have problems, you should provide a copy of the command & output so we can understand (not picture unless it's not text based).

Comment: Also FYI; use a @ before the name of the person you're speaking to. The system only told me because you (the Original Poster) replied to me, which is guessed because I was the only comment. If more than one person had commented, no-one gets notified unless a @guiverc or like name is used (the @ tells the system I'm mentioning a user of that name)

Comment: If you'd prefer support in your own language, may I suggest https://loco.ubuntu.com/  (LoCo = local community), or maybe IRC https://wiki.ubuntu.com/IRC/ChannelList  (scroll down to LoCo Ubuntu Channels; not all are as busy at others, but if you're patient, ask your request & leave the session open, people will respond when they can, even if it's hours later)